# Python any all vs sum to test for exact number defined variables in list?

Tags: python

I found this code and want to use the same logic for my own script. Basically it checks if none or both variables are set and raises an error:

```
if not any([self.inventory_item, self.device_type]) or all([self.inventory_item, self.device_type]):
            raise ValidationError(
                {
                    "inventory_item": "One and only one of `Inventory Item` OR `Device Type` must be specified.",
                    "device_type": "One and only one of `Inventory Item` OR `Device Type` must be specified.",
                }
            )
```

But I have a list of 3 items items to check where only one must be set. I have tried with sum, but got an TypeError back as those variables are not booleans.

```
sum([test1, test2, test3])
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

I wonder if there is a similar elegant solution to the problem to check if only one variable in a list of variables it set?

So the use case is that I have 3+ variables, if none is set it should throw an error, but if more than one is set as well.
if x=0 or x>1  False
if x == 1 True

Comment: What do you mean by ‘are set’? If either of those attributes are undefined, this code will always be a `TypeError`.

Comment: Does "are set" refer to not `None`?

Comment: You can use `sum(map(bool, [test1, test2, test3])) in (3, 0)`

Answer (score 1):

I might be misunderstanding your question but can't you just use `any(variables)`? or do you need to evaluate to true if and only if 1 variable is initialized? In which case you can use `sum([1 for x in variables if x])==1` Just note that None as well as empty strings and 0 all evaluate to false.

Comment: I guess he/she needs condition which checks either none or all values are set.

Comment: So what does "where only one must be set" mean?

Comment: I have no clue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do so, using [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter):

```
if len(list(filter(None, data))) != 1:
    # Raise error
```

---

Another way to do this is to count the number of occurrences of `None` in the list and compare it to the length of the list. Strangely, it's **much** faster.

```
if data.count(None) + 1 == len(data):
    # Raise error
```